# Convert ISpreadsheetName to CellRange

Tags: c#, .net, excel, telerik

I am using Telerik controls to manipulate Excel workbook. Here I am accessing Workbook Named Ranges the following way:

```
        ISpreadsheetName Name_Level2;
        workbook.Names.TryGetSpreadsheetName("IP_Stredisko_Level2_End", out Name_Level2);
```

Afterwards the result I get from `Name_Level2.RefersTo` is a plain string such as following:**"=Sheet1!$A$5"**

I am trying to convert this reference to a proper `CellRange` object, which can be used when manipulating specific cell values.

Is there any built-in method how to do the conversion, or I have to write the method myself?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, as I did not manage to find anything in the documentation, I have created my own converter. Hope it helps someone.

```
    private static CellRange GetCellRange(string sReference, string sWorkbookName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sReference))
            return null;

        sReference = sReference.Replace("=" + sWorkbookName + "!", string.Empty);
        sReference = sReference.Replace("$", string.Empty);

        string sColumn = string.Empty;
        string sRow = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < sReference.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(sReference[i]))
                sRow += sReference[i];
            else
                sColumn += sReference[i];
        }

        int iRow = Convert.ToInt16(sRow) -1;
        int iCol = GetColIndex(sColumn);

        if (iRow >= 0 && iCol >= 0)
            return new CellRange(iRow, iCol,iRow,iCol);
        else
            return null;
    }
    //accepting up to AZ
    private static int GetColIndex(string sReference)
    {
        if (sReference.Length > 1)
        {
            int x = (int)sReference[1];
            return 25 + ((int)sReference[1] - 65);//25 as 26 letters in alphabet -1 (start from 0)
        }

        return (int)sReference[0] - 65;
    }
```